# BrowserRouter redirect not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to redirect to login when entering the site. The redirect seems to work by looking at the URL but it's not rendering my Login component. I'm only including my return as I believe that's enough but let me know if it's not.

```
    return (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          state,
          dispatch
        }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        {!state.isAuthenticated ? <Redirect push to="/login"/> : <MyComponent state={state} AuthContext={AuthContext} />}
      </div>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/gallery" component={MyComponent} />
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
);
```

Updated return:

```
return (
<main>
<AuthContext.Provider
   value={{
      state,
      dispatch
   }}
>
   
</AuthContext.Provider>

<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/gallery" component={MyComponent} />
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      {!state.isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <MyComponent/>}
    </Route>
</Router>
</main>
);
```

Error:

> > 1636 | react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.render( /*#**PURE***/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["jsxDEV"])(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.StrictMode, {
> > |                                                  ^  1637 |   children: /*#**PURE***/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["jsxDEV"])(react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["BrowserRouter"], {
> > 1638 |     children: /*#**PURE***/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["jsxDEV"])(*components_App__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_["default"], {}, void 0, false, {
> > 1639 |       fileName: _jsxFileName,

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

Based on the latest edit there are some errors in the dom :

```js
return (
<main>
<AuthContext.Provider
   value={{
      state,
      dispatch
   }}
>
   
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/gallery" component={MyComponent} />
      <Route component={Error} />
      <Route exact path="/">
        {!state.isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <MyComponent/>}
      </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
</AuthContext.Provider>
</main>
);
```

Hope you are using `Router` as a alias of `BrowserRouter`.

This should solve your problem.

### Original

Use switch inside the browser router of react and also you can move Auth.Context outside the switch :

```js
<main>

<AuthContext.Provider
   value={{
      state,
      dispatch
   }}
>
   <div className="App">
      {!state.isAuthenticated ? <Redirect push to="/login"/> : 
          <MyComponent state={state} AuthContext={AuthContext} />}
   </div>
</AuthContext.Provider>

<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/gallery" component={MyComponent} />
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
</main>
```

You can import it from `react-router-dom` :

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Further if you want to redirect on a specific route the you can do some like :

```js
<Route exact path="/">
  {!state.isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <Dashboard/>}
</Route>
```

Please refrain from using components other than Route in switch.

Read more about it [here.](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: Thank you, that was a silly miss. However, it's still not rendering the component

Comment: Try moving Auth context outside the switch

Comment: Getting this error when moving it Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: [object Object]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Comment: I have added more improvement you can check it out. And you share the stack of the above error

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I have updated the OP with my current return, I believe it looks like the one you suggested? Added the errors as well

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check if it works

Comment: It's still getting the same error, Objects are not valid as a React child